# Keycloak create a custom identity provider mapper

Tags: jboss, keycloak, jboss-tools, jboss-eap-7, keycloak-services

i have an open id provider and i use this provider as identity broker of keycloak. I want to map roles (claims) which sent from broker to keycloak (and keycloak will sent mapped roles in its jwt). I want to know how to implement and add a custom mapper to keycloak (like hardcodedmapper, attributemapper in keycloak). Can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keycloak custom OpenID Connect Identity Provider mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584325/keycloak-custom-openid-connect-identity-provider-mapper)

Comment: Please, do not post questions twice. You can edit your question or whatever, if you find it takes long to be answered, ask in the keycloak user maillist.

Comment: Has anyone solution or suggestion about it?

Comment: Use a custom mapper that accesses your service and retrieves the extra info using REST API, DB connection or similar. Then add the info to your token before it gets encoded `initToken` or similar method in your custom mapper.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker thanks for answer, custom mapper means that identity provider mapper on keycloak, isn't it, how can i implement and add  a custom mapper to keycloak?

Comment: Yes, it is. You've got a bunch of examples here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers

Comment: @Xtreme Biker yes, i saw these source codes, i will implement a mapper like that, but how can i add(import) this custom mapper to keycloak as a mapper type,

Comment: Is there no one who can explain how to add or import custom mapper implementation to keycloak app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your new `provider` class, I extended the existing `org.keycloak.broker.saml.mappers.AttributeToRoleMapper` class.

When building your jar ensure you have a folder called services within the jars, META-INF folder.

Within this folder create a simple text file called `org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityProviderMapper`, within that file add the full name of your new provider class, i.e. `package.Classname`.

Once compiled drop the file in the providers folder below the Keycloak root folder.  Restart your container.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Are there an example code block or sample provider class (and or project.) Firstly, i will create a java library and i will i extend "org.keycloak.broker.saml.mappers.AttributeToRoleMapper" class, and then i will build it and drop it to keycloak_root/provider. am i right?          I do not understand clearly, please explain this sentence "When building your jar ensure you have a folder called services within the jars, META-INF folder."

Answer (score 5):

I had to do something slightly different in order to get my custom mapper working with the latest version of Keycloak (4.8 at time of writing this):

- Created a custom mapper that extends `AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper`:

  ```
  package com.test;

  import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper;

  public class MyTestMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper {
      ...
  }
  ```
- In `src/main/resources`, create a folder structure `META-INF/services`
- Create a file called `org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper` in `META-INF/services` directory.  Its contents should be just one line containing the fully qualified class name of your custom mapper:

  ```
  com.test.MyTestMapper
  ```
- Under the `META-INF` folder in `src/main/resources` (one up from `services`), create a file called `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.  Depending on what you're doing, you will need to add the appropriate JBoss modules here.  For my simple test mapper, I used:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jboss-deployment-structure>
      <deployment>
          <dependencies>
              <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
          </dependencies>
      </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
  ```

Comment: I'm doing something similar, where are you dropping your Jar ? I can't get it to show up in keycloak even though when I check standalone/deployments my jar shows as deployed

Comment: Your jar should go in /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/yourcode.jar