# Keycloak add extra claims from database / external source with custom protocol mapper

Tags: java, customization, keycloak

I've seen those two post that give a solution to this question but they do not provide detailed enough informations about how to do it for non Java developer like me:

[Keycloak add extra claims from database / external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376233/keycloak-add-extra-claims-from-database-external-source)

[How to register a custom ProtocolMapper in Keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523816/how-to-register-a-custom-protocolmapper-in-keycloak?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is a recap of their solutions that could help others if filled with more details.

**Process expected** *[from 1st link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376233/keycloak-add-extra-claims-from-database-external-source)*

> 1. User logs in
> 2. My custom protocol mapper gets called, where I overwrite the transformAccessToken method
> 3. Here I log in the client where the protocol mapper is in into keycloak, as a service. Here don't forget to use another client ID
>      instead the one you're building the protocol mapper for, you'll enter
>      an endless recursion otherwise.
> 4. I get the access token into the protocol mapper and I call the rest endpoint of my application to grab the extra claims, which is
>      secured.
> 5. Get the info returned by the endpoint and add it as extra claims

**Steps to achieve it** *[from 2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523816/how-to-register-a-custom-protocolmapper-in-keycloak?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

> Implement the ProtocolMapper interface and add the file
>   *"META-INF/services/org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper"* containing the reference to the class.
>
> At this point Keycloak recognizes the new implementation. And you
>   should be able to configure it via the admin console.
>
> To add some data to the token add the following interfaces
>
> *org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper*
>
> and implement the methods according to the interface
>
> Then add the file "*META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml*" with the
>   following content
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <jboss-deployment-structure>
>     <deployment>
>         <dependencies>
>             <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
>         </dependencies>
>     </deployment>
> </jboss-deployment-structure>
> ```
>
> And after doing all this the custom transformAccessToken() method is called
>   on every request to URL
>   http://:/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token

After reading this I have a few questions :

1. How do you ”Implement the ProtocolMapper”
2. Where do you add the files mentionned earlier ? ( can't see any META-INF/ directory in my Keycloak installation folder )
3. How and where do you ”add the following interfaces”
4. What does the custom transformAccessToken() looks like

Thank you all for your time. 
Let me know if I miss summarise their answers.

**Edit :**

I'm starting a bounty with the hope that someone will be able to give me detailled steps on how to add extra claims from database in Keycloak 3.4.3 ( Detailed enough for a non Java dev )

**Edit 2** 
A method descibed here could do the trick but lack details.
[Keycloak create a custom identity provider mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595425/keycloak-create-a-custom-identity-provider-mapper?rq=1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I hope this step by step guide helps you

I'm using Keycloak 4.5.0 - because I have this newer version installed - but I should not make a big difference. And I implemented a `OIDCProtocolMapper` in the example.

Just to summarize it - for the quick overview for others - each step is described more detailed later

1. You implement a CustomProtocolMapper class based on
   `AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper`
2. META-INF/services File with the
   name `org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper` must be available and
   contains the name of your mapper
3. `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` need to be available to use
   keycloak built in classes
4. Jar File is deployed in
   `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/`

Okay now more details :-)

### Create your custom Mapper

I uploaded you my maven `pom.xml` ([pom](https://pastebin.com/dkbw1SDW)) - just import it into your IDE and all the dependencies should be loaded automatically. The dependencies are just `provided`  and will be later used from keycloak directly at runtime

Relevant is the `keycloak.version` property - all keycloak dependencies are currently loaded in version `4.5.0.Final`

Now i created a custom Protocol Mapper Class called `CustomOIDCProtocolMapper`. Find "full" code [here](https://pastebin.com/kz9jpC5V)

It should extend `AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper` and need to implement all abstract methods. Maybe you want to have a SAML Protocol Mapper then it's another base class (`AbstractSAMLProtocolMapper`)

one relevant method is `transformAccessToken` - here I set a additional Claim to the AccessToken. You need your logic here but yeah - depends on your database, etc. ;-)

### Services File

The services File is **important** for keycloak to find your custom-Implementation

Place a file with the **fileName** `org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper` inside `\src\main\resources\META-INF\services\`

Inside this file you write to Name of your custom Provider - so keycloak knows that this class is available as Protocol Mapper
In my example the file content is just one line

```
com.stackoverflow.keycloak.custom.CustomOIDCProtocolMapper
```

### Deployment Structure XML

In your custom mapper you use files from keycloak. In order to use them we need to inform jboss about this dependency. 
Therefore create a file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` inside `\src\main\resources\META-INF\` 
Content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

### Build and deploy your Extension

Build a jar File of your Extension (`mvn clean package`) - and place the `jar` in `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/` and restart keycloak

In the logfile you should see when it's deployed and (hopefully no) error messages

Now you can use your mapper - In my example I can create a Mapper in keycloak admin ui  and select `Stackoverflow Custom Protocol Mapper` from dropdown

Just as info - this is not fully official supported by keycloak - so interfaces could possible change in later versions

I hope it's understandable and you will be able to succesfully implement your own mapper

EDIT:
Exported eclipse file structure [zip](http://www.filedropper.com/keycloak-customprotocolmapper)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer !

From Eclipse I imported the pom.xml
I added a "Source Folder" in which I created a class `CustomOIDCProtocolMapper` in a folder / package `com.stackoverflow.keycloak.custom`

I believe I'm good so far but next step require the \src\main\resources\META-INF\services\ folder. 
I don't find it in the Maven project nor the Keycloak installation folder in which I only find `bin`  `docs`  `domain`  `jboss-modules.jar`  `License.html`  `LICENSE.txt`  `modules`  `standalone`  `themes`  `version.txt`  `welcome-content`

Comment: You don't need to place any File (except .jar) inside keycloak directories. Just create the folderpath in eclipse. Everything is then packaged within the jar. I'll provide you later my whole eclipse project

Comment: Thank you, 
I created the folderpath and I'm currently stuck with the error `Provider com.stackoverflow.keycloak.custom.CustomOIDCProtocolMapper not found` when uploading the jar to keycloak
My paths are 
 _/com/stackoverflow/keycloak/custom/CustomOIDCProtocolMapper.java_ 
 _/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper_
_/src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml_

Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: I accepted your answers because I'm now able to select this custom mapper in the drop down.
I'll try to understand why the `stackoverflowCustomToken` claim is not in the generated access token.
Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I've tried to follow the instructions provided by @Evil_skunk 
my project is successfully deployed on JBoss and I can see that it is loaded when starting JBoss. 
However, when I go into the Keycloak admin UI I can't see it.
In the admin UI, I'm going into `Clients > Account > Mapper > Create` and I can't find my Mapper in the select box called `Mapper Type`. 
Not sure if I'm missing something?
My code is here: https://github.com/michaelisvy/keycloak-protocol-mapper/tree/master/

Comment: @MichaelIsvy - I've not tested your code, but it looks like your service file (https://github.com/michaelisvy/keycloak-protocol-mapper/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.acme.DemoProtocolMapper) has the wrong name (content is correct !) - rename it too `org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper`

Comment: The _this is not fully official supported by keycloak - so interfaces could possible change in later versions_ comment is spot on. FYI I used the code in https://github.com/mschwartau/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper-example which follows pretty much the same steps and at runtime, Keycloak 8 logs a warning `KC-SERVICES0047: ... is implementing the internal SPI protocol-mapper. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
`

Comment: @Luis do you have your working code publicly on github?  I tried to follow mschwartau example and I cannot get my custom protocol mapper to show up in the "Add Builtin Protocol Mapper" list.  However, I am on Keycloak 9.0.2.

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés : Sorry, I don't have the code in github but the process was straightforward after updating the dependencies to Keycloak 8.0.0 and resteasy 3.9.0.Final, fixing a build error and removing the `-SNAPSHOT` references so I could use the jar from my Keycloak pom.xml (I'm currently running it in maven through spring-boot)

Comment: @Luis no worries, I found where my mistake was, and I can now use my custom protocol mapper.  Cheers!

Comment: Using Docker Keycloak 20.0.2 (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2), to make it works, I had to copy the jar file to /opt/keycloak/providers/

Answer (score 3):

I am using a **Custom Protocol Mapper**<sup>1</sup> to send an **authenticated**<sup>2</sup> **GraphQL query**<sup>3</sup> to an external system and put the JSON response data into the user's access token (JWT). It currently runs with Keycloak 10.

==> You can find the full code in [this repository](https://github.com/tholst/keycloak-json-graphql-remote-claim).

#### (1) Custom Protocol Mapper

As others have noted, your project needs at least 3 files.

1. A Java class that implements `AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper` & its method `setClaim` (among others).
2. A `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file that contains the dependencies for deployment.
3. An `org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper` file that contains the full name of the custom protocol mapper.

Here is the folder structure:

```sh
$ tree src/ -A
src/
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── thohol
    │           └── keycloak
    │               └── JsonGraphQlRemoteClaim.java
    └── resources
        └── META-INF
            ├── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
            └── services
                └── org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper
```

#### (2) Authenticated Remote Requests

If the **remote endpoint requires authentication**, we can **obtain an Access Token from Keycloak**. The complete flow would look as follows (especially steps 3-6):

1. A user sends an authentication request (i.e., "logs in") to Keycloak. The request is made against a specific Keycloak client, e.g., `login-client`.
2. Because the `login-client` is configured to use the Custom Protocol Mapper, its code gets executed while the user's authentication request is being processed.
3. The Custom Protocol Mapper sends a second authentication request to Keycloak. The request is made against a *second* Keycloak client (e.g., `remote-claims-client`) using `client_credentials` (Client ID + Secret).
4. The Custom Protocol Mapper receives an access token for client `remote-claims-client`.
5. The Custom Protocol Mapper sends a request to the remote endpoint. An `Authorization: Bearer <access token>` header is added to the request headers.
6. The remote endpoint receives the request and validates the JWT token. In many cases, access should be restricted further. For example, to only allow tokens minted ("written") for the corresponding `remote-claims-client`.
7. The remote endpoint returns the custom remote claims data.
8. The Custom Protocol Mapper receives the custom remote claims data and puts it into the user's access token.
9. Keycloak returns an access token with custom claims to the user.

Steps 3/4 can be implemented as a simple HTTP POST request in Java (error handling omitted!):

```java
// Call remote service
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(keycloakAuthUrl);
URI uri = uriBuilder.build();

HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri);
String queryBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=remote-claims-client&client_secret=dfebc62a-e8d7-4ab3-9196-258ddb5684ab";
builder.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(queryBody));

// Build headers
builder.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE , MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

// Call
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(builder.build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

// Process Response
JsonNode json = return new ObjectMapper().readTree(response.body());
String accessToken = json.findValue("access_token").asText();
```

#### (3) Using GraphQL Queries for external requests

A GraphQL query is essentially an HTTP POST request, with a `body` like

```
{
    "query": "query HeroName($episode: Episode) {
        hero(episode: $episode) {
            name
        }
    }",
    "variables": {
        "episode" : "JEDI"
    }
}
```

This can be sent from Java like (error handling omitted!):

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(remoteUrl);
URI uri = uriBuilder.build();

HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri);
String queryBody = "{
    \"query\": \"query HeroName($episode: Episode) {
        hero(episode: $episode) {
            name
        }
    }\",
    \"variables\": {
        \"episode\" : \"JEDI\"
    }
}";
builder.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(queryBody));

// Build headers
builder.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken);

// Call
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(builder.build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

// Process Response and add to token
JsonNode json = return new ObjectMapper().readTree(response.body());
clientSessionCtx.setAttribute("custom_claims", json);
```

#### Disclaimer

I am the owner/author of the linked repository. However, I did not start from scratch but used multiple other repositories as basis/inspiration. See the [repo's README](https://github.com/tholst/keycloak-json-graphql-remote-claim/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Can I pass some variables from steps 5 to 7 so that custom claims are fetched on that variable information?