# Keycloak Custom Claims : Can you add parameters at runtime while querying external database

Tags: java, spring, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Purpose: I want to fetch custom claims based on certain fields passed to keycloak custom implementation, which is internal to the application and not present within keycloak. I am working on migrating a legacy application in spring to keycloak for authentication but we want to continue to use the existing application's authorization. Existing authorization is ABAC based and is heavily dependent on dynamic resources.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311019/3534593) solution to create custom mappers and claims. Can I pass some variables before step # 5, so that custom claims are fetched on that variable-based information? I have not yet tried implementing it but assuming that this will be internally called by Keycloak, (I have implemented User Storage SPI so I assumed that).

Eg:

The user has a mapping to resource_1, which depends upon which Project (internal to the application and not stored within keycloak) the user belongs to.
So based on the user as well as its project_id, I want to call the external database and fetch the mapping to the resource.

Challenge:

> How and where do I pass the project_id? I cannot store it in keycloak
> because it is dynamic and not static.  Is it even possible?

One more eg,

Some value that I would like to put in the claim for my situation which can only be transferred via HTTP request, like below, but in Java custom mapper implementation,

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tsp_openapi/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=_N7IcTaPF3vTtkPtIKQweKyCQRaXyVu2JF-fgcWQd40&execution=8975a242-0d40-4a47-992c-6ea7dd91728e&client_id=pplantoo&tab_id=fXCfFj3BG2c&**project_id=2232123321**
```

Comment: Do you want to send the `project_id` as a parameter because you don't have access to it in Keycloak OR is it because it's really dynamic and can be different every time a user tries to login to the Keycloak?

Comment: because it's really dynamic and can be different every time a user tries to access a REST API endpoint. A user passes it currently to the APIs

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to access the parameters coming in the request in the authenticator implementation. Otherwise, you could store those parameters in the authentication session and then access them via `KeycloakSession` object that would be accessible in your mapper implementation. I remember once I needed to do something dynamic based on a parameter passed to Keycloak, and there were no way to access them based on Keycloak's domain model :(

Comment: I came across this https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_authorization_my_resources Do you think it is a good idea to store resources in Keycloak and authorize them via this model? I haven't read the document in its entirety, but based on a quick glance, it seems to have something to do with what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes. That's the way the Authorization works in Keycloak (and generally all such IdP servers). It's based on the well-known patterns like PDP/PEP/PIP/PAP. But that's a big topic. You should really think about it thoroughly and do some proof of concepts before getting into it. It's generally a chatty protocol, but maybe if you just try to define your resources there (and not the resource instances) then it would be OK. I have never used it before, but seems quite comprehensive if you know how to utilize it in your system.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/9.0/authorization_services/ This says that claims can be dynamically added to the token in Claim Information Point (CIP), CIP is a part of Policy Enforcement Point (PEP). PEP is a (or can be) one of the Keycloak OIDC adapters. You mentioned the PEP pattern above. Are these 2 talking about the same thing? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, they're the same thing. Unfortunately as I mentioned, I don't have experiences in this part of the Keycloak. But I'll put what I found as an answer, as I would not be read only as a comment.

Comment: When you say, "Otherwise, you could store those parameters in the authentication session and then access them via KeycloakSession object that would be accessible in your mapper implementation." Does this also mean that I have to implement my User Storage SPI for accessing authentication sessions? Where do I access it?

Comment: The KeycloakSession is available almost to all sorts of providers that you can implement and it gives you an access point to call Keycloak APIs. It normally gets passed to the provider factory classes as a constructor parameter. But as I mentioned, I didn't manage to find a way to access request parameters in authenticators to put in the KeycloakSession.

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in the comments and based on what I can see in the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/9.0/authorization_services/), you can setup the Keycloak adapter on your client application to also act as a Policy Enforcer Point, aka. PEP by updating your `keycloak.json` with attributes like this

```json
"policy-enforcer": {
    "paths": [
      {
        "path": "/protected/resource",
        "claim-information-point": {
          "claims": {
            "project_id_claim": "{request.parameter['project_id']}"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

By doing so, the Keycloak adapter will send a request to Keycloak authorization server together with the `project_id_claim` to see if current user (that owns the current token) is allowed to access requested URL or not.
I think then you may be able to add a custom policy (e.g. using [JavaScript-Based Policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_js)) to query your db or backend service to see if given user with provided project_id is authorized or not. If that doesn't work, I guess you should try implementing a custom "PolicyProvider" interface and use that one instead. However I'm not sure how/if it would appear in the UI.

I should mention that I have never tried this before and these are all based on my experiences on how similar stuff is done the Keycloak and reading their documentation.

Comment: Thanks for adding it as an answer, but I am still not 100% sure if I want to introduce PEP and Javascript code. If I did not come up with any other solution,I will accept it.
Meanwhile I found this. Requesting Claims using the “claims” Request Parameter: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimsParameter what do you think of this?
It says that we can pass parameters during runtime while fetching remote claims. And JWT will then contain distributed claims/aggregate claims. But for this, we might have to implement our authenticator. I am testing it right now to see if works

Comment: I was not aware of that. Seems like a viable solution for what you're trying to do