# Keycloak - Use Client scope with client_credentials and authorization code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

I have a RESTful API that is consumed by a browser frontend and multiple machine-to-machine clients. So I'm issuing tokens with Keycloak 18 through Standard Flow (Authorization code) and Service Account Flow (Client credentials).

The operations on the API's resources are protected by scopes like `read:resourceA`, `update:resourceA`, `read:resourceB`, etc.

When I assign a Realm Role to a Client Scope, and if I map a user to the same Realm Role, the tokens issued through the Authorization Code Flow (browser frontend) contain the scope.

Also, when I create a Machine-to-Machine client and I add to Client Scope directly to the Client, the tokens for the M2M client also contain the scope.

So far so good. But as soon as I try to do both at the same time, I no longer have the scope in tokens issued by the M2M-client.

It seems that adding a Client Scope to a Role makes it impossible to use that scope otherwise.

The obvious, but bad solution would be to create a second set of scopes for this kind of client. Is there any other solution I'm not aware of?

I'm migrating from Auth0.com to Keycloak, and that's currently the only point blocking me from finishing this migration.

Thanks,
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I missed the concept of `Service Account Roles`. For all those running into the same troubles:

**How to add a new Role to an Authorization code flow client**

- Create client with Default Flow enabled
- Create client role
- In Client Scope Settings, add the new client role to the scope
- In Client Settings, add the scope(s) to the list of default scopes
- Add the new client role to the user

**How to add a new M2M client**

- Create the new client
- Create a new client role in the Client settings
- In the Client settings, in the tab `Service Account Roles`, assign the new Client Role
- In the Client scope settings, assign the new client role
- In Client Settings, add the scope(s) to the list of default scopes

Answer (score 3):

In a standards based approach, scopes are composed of claims. [Scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) are fixed at design time, whereas [claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) have runtime values. So at runtime a particular client and user may result in these values:

```
- myscope
  - roles: [user, admin]
  - subscription-level: gold
```

An example is the built-in `profile` scope, which includes name and email claims, and might look like this at runtime:

```
- profile
  - name: John Doe
  - email: john@doe.io
```

It is recommended to avoid `scope explosion`, as you suggest. In Keycloak I would keep scopes the same for all clients, so that nothing changes in the client interface.

A `realm role` is a type of claim, though a Keycloak specific concept I think. Perhaps you can represent it differently, or configure a realm role for the M2M client also?

Comment: thanks for the reply! The difference between scopes and claims was indeed a bit fuzzy in my head :-)
In Keycloak there are Realm Roles (global) and Client Roles ("namespaced" roles). The problem remains the same with Client Roles though. Having the scope in the JWT seems only to work with Role/User/AuthorizationCodeFlow or with Scope attached to Client directly and without any attachment to Roles. Attaching the Scope to a Client Role doesn't have any effect on the Tokens Scopes either.

Comment: It feels like behaviour related to attaching scopes to roles is the issue here. A role is just a type of claim though, so I would maybe avoid doing this, and perhaps look at [custom claims handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089776/keycloak-add-extra-claims-from-database-external-source-with-custom-protocol-m) instead. It may be a little more work, but could be worth it to get the architecture right.